# make clear factors

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the exact meaning of "make clear factors" in the following passage? I guess it means "realize, recognize, knowing" but I am not sure. It is mentionable the text is from a political telegram.

> I believe this impression created in part by …. and in part by failure his Ministers to make clear factors responsible for our decision tentatively to turn over about $5 million monthly to the Bank to be sold for pitas.

Comment: The "sold for pitas" makes me think that perhaps you have copied the text incorrectly.  Do you have a source?

Comment: Please always cite your source so that we can compare it to be sure it's correct. There are many errors in this and I agree that this is not copied correctly.

Comment: @Catija As near as I can tell (see my Comment below), it is in fact accurate, except for *pitas*; as OP says, it's a diplomatic telegram.

Comment: @StoneyB which is why I said that citing the source is important. Telegrams are specifically written in shorthand to limit the amount that has to be transmitted, which means that they (as you pointed out) omit words that aren't necessarily necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew23's mention of "sold for pitas" and some obviously missing words also give me the impression that you may have copied the text incorrectly.  Two words have to be added to make the sentence grammatically correct:

> ...and in part by *the* failure *of* his ministers to make clear factors responsible for our decision...

(It could also be *a* failure.)

From there, there are some words missing that are implied.  Simply putting them in should clarify the meaning for you:

> ...and in part by the failure of his ministers to make clear *the* factors *that are* responsible for our decision...

It's easy to think of the original as having the meaning of "...make some clear factors responsible...," which would certainly be confusing.

Comment: It may be accurate; the source *Foreign Relations of the United States 1952-1954:Iran*, apparently a telegram from the US Ambassador in Iran to the State Department (it's available only in snippet view), which would account for missing articles and prepositions. *Pitas* appears to be an error for "rials".

Comment: @StoneyB  Interesting!  That makes complete sense, that it was a telegram charging by the word.  My grandparents would always sign telegrams to my dad "MOMDAD" when I was little.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The usual pattern is

```
to make {something} clear
```

> I want to make {this explanation} clear.

However, when {something} is a long phrase, "clear" will be moved ahead of {something}.

> I want to **make** {my reasons for taking the shortcut through the school
>   cafeteria to the gym} **clear**.

becomes

> I want to **make clear** {my reasons for taking the shortcut through the school
>   cafeteria to the gym}.

Thus, what was being avoided in your example was this:

> **make**  {factors responsible for our decision tentatively to turn over about $5 million monthly to the Bank to be sold for pitas}
>   **clear**.